# JBoss Fuse Server not starting, giving below error

Tags: jbossfuse, karaf, fuseesb

I am getting below error in Fuse log :

```
`Sep 14, 2017 5:21:57 AM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
Sep 14, 2017 5:21:58 AM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
Sep 14, 2017 5:21:59 AM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
Sep 14, 2017 5:22:00 AM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: locking
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens because there is already another Fuse instance running, with the same current directory. If you started Fuse in a way that doesn't create a console, it's not difficult to forget that you did so, and try to start it again. Fuse is designed to work this way -- it's not an error to try to start multiple instances with the same working directory: this is often done for redundancy. But it can be hard to spot if you've done it by accident. Use "jps" or something to see if another JVM is running.

There are other potential causes of this problem that can be explored, but it's worth ruling out the simple explanations first.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Yes your are right the cause is multiple Fuse instance running and i had bymistakely tried to run the fuse.sh for the second time due to which SimpleFileLock is being called. Fuse is installed in Linux system and i would have to kill the process but i am not sure how will i identify this instance and kill. Appreciate your response.  In below link someone faced same issuebut didnt mention how exactly he fixed it. https://developer.jboss.org/message/909889#909889

Comment: Try "ps -ef | grep java" and look for processes that have "-Dkaraf.home=..." in the command line. If there more than one of these process, you can use the karaf.home value to decide which ones are like candidates to be removed. Then use "kill" to stop them.

Comment: Thanks that helped to find the two instance but the problem now is that both the process point to same karaf home i.e "-Dkaraf.home=" has same value for both processes . So now i am confused which process to kill.

Comment: Yeah, that can be tricky. Try using "lslocks" to  see which process has a lock on data/cache/cache.lock. Most likely the process that has successfully locked it will be the "real" process, and any other will be waiting to lock it, and won't be doing anything useful at present.

Comment: Ok will try this but just informing you one strange thing i noticed. Since i started facing this issue of Lock my Server goes down i mean System on which JBoss is installed. Do you think that this lock is causing the system to shutdown?

Comment: I would not expect this. The lock just controls which processes can start. If a Fuse process stops unexpectedly, there is usually a clue in its log.